# Copy only selected rows without not-selected rows between in RowHeaderSelect mode

Tags: c#, datagridview, selection

I'm looking for a possibility in C# in Windows Forms Application to be able to:

1. Select multiple, full rows at a time.
2. Include unselected rows between the selected ones.
3. Then copy them to the clipboard without empty spaces (which are left for the unselected rows).

The `DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect` doesn't cut it as I also need to be able to select independent cells. I need to enable the same behaviour in row copying as the `DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect` has but for the `DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect` mode. Would that be possible to do?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

First, to do this we will be manually removing the empty lines from the default copy results. We will call the following method to do so:

```
private void StripEmptyFromCopy()
{
    string[] separated = Clipboard.GetText().Split('\n').Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToArray();
    string copy = String.Join("\n", separated);

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(copy))
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(copy);
    }
}
```

**Solutions and Cons**

1. My initial thought was to do this by handling the `DataGridView.KeyUp` event, checking the user input for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>:

   ```
   private void dataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.KeyCode == Keys.C && (Control.Modifiers & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
       {
           StripEmptyFromCopy();
           e.Handled = true;
       }
   }
   ```

   - Works fine if <kbd>C</kbd> is released first. If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is released first, the empty rows are still in the Clipboard.
2. Create your own class inherting from `DataGridView` and override `ProcessCmdKey`:

   ```
   public class CopyDataGridView : DataGridView
   {
       protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
       {
           if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C))
           {
               StripEmptyFromCopy();
               return false;
           }

           return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
       }
   }
   ```

   - Returning `True` after calling `StripEmptyFromCopy` prevents the Clipboard from getting the copy. Returning `False` works... but then gets overridden by the default copy and I don't know where this occurs.
3. Combine these ideas to catch <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> no matter which key is released first in the `KeyUp` event handler:

   ```
   public class CopyDataGridView : DataGridView
   {
       public bool Copying { get; set; }

       protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
       {
           Copying = keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.C);
           return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
       }
   }

   // And in the form:
   copyDataGridView1.KeyUp += CopyDataGridView1_KeyUp;

   private void CopyDataGridView1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (copyDataGridView1.Copying)
       {
           StripEmptyFromCopy();
           copyDataGridView1.Copying = false;
           e.Handled = true;
       }
   }
   ```

   - It's more work, but it gives consistent results vs. option 1.