# Keypress modifiers in a DataGridView with and without data

Tags: c#, datagridview, keyboard-shortcuts, keydown

I am trying to implement a CTRL+C Copy operation in a usercontrol derived from a DataGridView.

I want Ctrl+C to copy the selected cells in the datagridview, and Ctrl+Shift+C to copy the selected cells **and** the cell column header text.

I have set up two copy routines, and they work fine.  The problem I am having is assigning the key_down handlers.

Here is my keyDown code:

```
 protected virtual void DataGridViewEx_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("KeyCode = " + e.KeyCode.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("KeyValue = " + e.KeyValue.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("KeyData = " + e.KeyData.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Modifiers = " + e.Modifiers.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-------------------------------");


        if ((e.Control & e.Shift) && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CTRL+SHIFT+C Pressed");
            CopyToClipboard(CopyMode.SelectedCellsWithHeaders);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("CTRL+C Pressed");
            CopyToClipboard(CopyMode.SelectedCellsOnly);
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        else if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
        {
            PasteClipboard();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Now:  Here is the bit I don't understand:
When I try this on an empty grid (i.e. no data, columns etc), I get the following:

Ctrl+C:

> KeyCode = C
>   KeyValue = 67
>   KeyData = C, Shift, Control
>   Modifiers = Shift, Control

Ctrl+Shift+C

> KeyCode = C
>   KeyValue = 67
>   KeyData = C, Shift, Control
>   Modifiers = Shift, Control

BUT:  Once I've pasted data into the grid, the exact same keydown operations yield this:

Ctrl+C

> KeyCode = C
>   KeyValue = 67
>   KeyData = C, Control
>   Modifiers = Control

Ctrl+Shift+C

> KeyCode = ShiftKey 
>   KeyValue = 16 
>   KeyData = ShiftKey, Shift, Control
>   Modifiers = Shift, Control

The "C" Keypress is no longer being recognized when there is data in the grid, and I am only getting the Ctrl+Shift.

The cells aren't in edit mode (you can see that Ctrl+C works fine).  I can change it to something like Ctrl+K instead, but I would like to understand what may be happening here.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key modifiers have some peculiar behaviors in the `KeyDown` event handlers. To handle modifier checks for your special copying needs, I would suggest following [the 3rd part of my solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32876845/3773066), with modifications. Namely, create a class to inherit from `DataGridView`:

```
public class CopyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public bool ProcessShiftCopy { get; set; }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        ProcessShiftCopy = keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.C);
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Then follow these steps:

1. Replace your `DataGridView` with an instance of `CopyDataGridView`.
2. Handle the `CopyDataGridView.KeyUp` event instead of `DataGridView.KeyDown`. This is because `KeyDown` will not trigger the key modifiers the way we want, but `KeyUp` will.
3. Replace:

   ```
   if ((e.Control & e.Shift) && e.KeyCode == Keys.C)
   ```

   with:

   ```
   if (yourCopyDataGridView.ProcessShiftCopy)
   ```

   to handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: Thank-you!  It works, and I think I know what was happening.  I looked at what ProcessCmdKey does from here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).   I see that it checks whether the control has a context menu.  Well, my control does have a context menu, but it only shows if there is data in the Datagridview.  I think this is what was happening in my example, where it was working with no data loaded - that is when the context menu wouldn't be shown.